# Laravel Eloquent - update with join

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I tried to do updates with join as below but it doesn't work..no error

Any ideas ?

```
        $updates = Schedule::join('production_wip', function ($q) {
                $q->on('schedule.DJ_NBR', '=', 'production_wip.DJ_NBR')
                  ->on('schedule.dept_code', '=', 'production_wip.Dept_Code');
            })
            ->where('schedule.skipped', '!=', 1)->whereNull('schedule.actual_production')
            ->update(['schedule.skipped' => 1]);
```

Comment: I found my problem --> Join I used is actually inner join..
I need left join to make it work >> So I changed join ---> leftjoin

Comment: you forgot to return the result of your query inside the closure also.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug it with that :

```php
DB::enableQueryLog();
$results = Schedule::join('production_wip', function ($q) {
                $q->on('schedule.DJ_NBR', '=', 'production_wip.DJ_NBR')
                  ->on('schedule.dept_code', '=', 'production_wip.Dept_Code');
            })
            ->where('schedule.skipped', '!=', 1)->whereNull('schedule.actual_production')
            ->get();

dd($results, DB::getQueryLog());
```

To ensure that your query is affecting some rows (you can check the SQL generated and try it in Sequel Ace (or any other DB Manager)

I bet that the problem is that either your data are not formated the same way in your 2 tables, or you have no data matching your were()